Why is a נשר - eagle considered שקץ - a detestable thing when its symbol is used on many holy things
The word "שקץ" is described by R. Samson Rafael Hirsch as follows, "...the prohibition against eating (an eagle, or other similar birds) is termed שקץ, such eating is antithetical to that morality which must be the basis of our existence. Whereas טומאה only impedes holiness, שקץ leads to its very opposite."
If so, why is a נשר - eagle (which some call a griffon-vulture), eagle considered "שקץ - a detestable thing" when its symbol is used on many holy things such as the curtains of the Mishkan (where an eagle was woven - [Yoma 72b])?
Furthermore, describing the manner in which G‑d had brought the children of Israel out of Egypt, G‑d said, "And I carried you on eagles' wings and brought you unto Me." [Shemos 19:4]. Is the eagle still considered detestable?
Additionally, the eagle is the symbol of mercy (Rachamim) in Jewish thought [Zohar III, 233a]. This Divine quality is symbolized by the image of an "eagle's face" in the vision of the Heavenly Throne, which the Prophet describes [Yechezkel - 1:10].
Why use such a word of שקץ on such a beautiful and seemingly holy Jewish symbol?

Look into the Lubavitcher Rebbes teachings about unpure animals

Lion is also not kosher but it's image is in the third beis hamikdash etc

@msh210 why did you delete my answer? I have additional info/ references. Nesher / Snake was the image on the Shevet Dan flag. What is wrong?
